# Using Interfaces in vba for using same function for different kind of type

Tags: vba, excel, function, types

Function "AddWeight" can add weight to every pet. I know that all of my animal (Inherit) have basicInfo type with same name ("data"), so I'm sure that "AddWeight" function can properly handle it.

Of course Vba will not let me to do that, I tried to declare in function title on object or variant.. nothing of them work for me.

Does anyone have a creative idea?

I don't want to write this function for every animal and I also don't find it elegant to call function like that:

```
Call addWeight(Max_Cat.data)
```

Does someone have another idea? Thanks in advance

```
   Type basicInfo
                name As string
                weight as integer
                height as integer
            End Type

            Type cat
                data As basicInfo
                mustacheType As String
            End Type

            Type dog
                data As basicInfo
                bark_volume as integer
            End Type

       Dim Max_Cat as cat
       Dim Buddy_Dog as dog
    .
    .   some code
    .
        Call addWeight(Max_Cat)
        Call addWeight(Buddy_Dog) 


        Public Function AddWeight(petName as object) 'not work also for petName as variant
        petName.data.weight =petName.data.weight+50

        End Function
```

Comment: why not use classes? Or a module that gives the type name? Module "cat" : cat.addweight(petname as cat)

Comment: Do you mean `petName.data.weight =petName.data.weight+50` rather than `petName.date.weight =petName.date.weight+50`?

Comment: @Pierre not sure i understand your answer or how to do that, will class can work as a type?

Comment: @David: no, class does not work as a type, but is an alternative.
If you really need different types, the only way I know about is to create a module with your typename, and use the module name as a prefix.
For example, you wanna code "toString" with long and doubles: you create modules Lng and Dbl, and use Lng.tostring(MyLong) or Dbl.ToString(MyDouble)

Comment: @Pierre sure , took me a while to see the difference you got great eyes. i just edit again my question , it's DATA thanks

Comment: "i also don't find it elegant to ..." VBA isn't an elegant language. `Call addWeight(Max_Cat.data)` is readable enough. `addWeight Max_Cat.data` is even more so. In VBA, readability is often a sufficient accomplishment. @Pierre is undoubtedly correct that if you want something more elegant, you will have to abandon types in favor of classes.

Comment: @David If you want to use Interfaces, you'll need to get into programming with classes.  [Chip Pearson's](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx) web site has useful information regarding [Interfaces and Implementation](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Implements.aspx) as well as an [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx).  Although programming with classes may be a bit slower than using `Type`, they are more flexible and perhaps easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this isn't "inheritance" in the strictest sense of the word.  It's more like a composite structure.  If you want to represent your data using `Type`s, the obvious solution is to just pass the *member* that you want to work with, i.e. the `basicInfo`:

```
Sub SomeSub()
    Dim Max_Cat As cat
    Dim Buddy_Dog As dog

    'Other stuff.
    AddWeight Max_Cat.data
    AddWeight Buddy_Dog.data
End Sub

Public Function AddWeight(animal As basicInfo)
    animal.weight = animal.weight + 50
End Function
```

If you *really* want to use interfaces, you'll need to build classes instead of types.  That way you can have them implement a common interface, then use the interface as the parameter.  This is probably going to give you much more robust and extensible code.